# Column required to be shared by 2 embedded type but cause "Repeated column in mapping for entity"

Tags: java, jpa

I wonder if any one can give me a suggestion about design? I encounter the problem as following:  org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity, which I know it is because I used the same column ("uom") for 2 embedded getters. However, by definition the column that is repeated is shared by the other 2 columns. Can anyone suggest how to design it with JPA annotation?

```
public class FinalProfile extends BlockSegment implements Serializable, DeepCopy {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ...
    private Measurement thresholdElevation;
    ...
    private Measurement thresholdCrossingHeight;




    public Measurement getThresholdCrossingHeight() {
        return thresholdCrossingHeight;
    }

    public void setThresholdCrossingHeight(Measurement thresholdCrossingHeight) {
        this.thresholdCrossingHeight = thresholdCrossingHeight;
    }

    public Measurement getThresholdElevation() {
        return thresholdElevation;
    }

    public void setThresholdElevation(Measurement thresholdElevation) {
        this.thresholdElevation = thresholdElevation;
    }

    ...
}


@Entity
@EntityListeners( { AuditEntityListener.class, HasFlightProcedureIdEntityListener.class, HasAlpExpansionEntityListener.class } )
@Table ( name = "FINAL_PROFILE" )
@DiscriminatorValue ( "1" )
public class FinalProfileDo extends BlockSegmentDo 
        implements Audited, HasFlightProcedureId, HasAlpExpansionData {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final Long BlockSegmentId = 1L;

    private FinalProfile finalProfile;
    ...


        @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides ( { 
        @AttributeOverride ( name = "value", column = @Column ( name = "THLD_CROSS_HEIGHT" ) )
        , @AttributeOverride ( name = "uom", column = @Column ( name = "TCH_UOM" ) )
    } )
    public MeasurementDo getThresholdCrossingHeight() {
        return (MeasurementDo)this.finalProfile.getThresholdCrossingHeight();
    }

    @DeepCopyType ( MeasurementDo.class )
    public void setThresholdCrossingHeight(Measurement thresholdCrossingHeight) {
        this.finalProfile.setThresholdCrossingHeight(thresholdCrossingHeight);
    }

        @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride( name ="value", column = @Column (name = "THLD_ELEVATION") ) 
        , @AttributeOverride ( name = "uom", column = @Column ( name = "TCH_UOM"))
    })
    public MeasurementDo getThresholdElevation() {
        return (MeasurementDo)this.finalProfile.getThresholdElevation();
    }

    @DeepCopyType ( MeasurementDo.class )
    public void setThresholdElevation(MeasurementDo thresholdElevation) {
        this.finalProfile.setThresholdElevation(thresholdElevation);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in `name = "uom", column = @Column ( name = "TCH_UOM")` rows, the `@Embedded` attribute create column in the entity table, you try to create two column with same name in the same table.

Comment: The column is shared, so I have to use the same name. I understand why JPA reports error, because I should NOT use the same column (TCH_UOM) for both embedded type at the same time. I wonder if there is any alternate design, so I can use JPA while reflects that the TCH_UOM column is shared by both embedded types?

Comment: if you show more code about that entities I can help you

Comment: Here is part of code, forgive me for that i am NOT allowed to publish all of code: